# Regularity of harmonic functions with robin data up to the boundary

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I want to prove that if $u$ is a solution of 
$\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$ with Robin boundary conditions $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \lambda u$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has analytic boundary, then $u$ is analytic  up to the boundary (i.e. there exists analytic extension of $u$ to $U \supset \overline{\Omega}$). I know that showing that $u \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$ would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the book by Lions and Magenes: Non-homogeneous boundary value problems and applications, vol 3, in the chapter about elliptic iterates.

Comment: To be precise: Corollary 1.1 in section 1.2 in Chapter 8 of Lions and Magenes.